# Make a count for distinct values in Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I have duplicate ids in my db and wish to get the count for distinct values only similar to   SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column) FROM table in SQL.

```
public SearchSourceBuilder createQueryForCount(QueryBuilder queryBuilder, int start, boolean fetchSource, String field){
        logger.info("Creating aggregation count ");

        QueryBuilder finalQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(queryBuilder);

        AggregationBuilder aggregationCount = AggregationBuilders.terms("agg").field(USER_ID)
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.topHits("top").explain(false).from(start))
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("count").field(field));

        return new SearchSourceBuilder()
                .query(finalQuery)
                .fetchSource(fetchSource)
                .from(start)
                .aggregation(aggregationCount);

    }
```

Is there a way to do a distinct count in Elastic search?

Answer (score 0):

You should look for Cardinality Aggregation. Javadocs are available [here](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.4.1/org/elasticsearch/search/aggregations/metrics/cardinality/CardinalityAggregationBuilder.html). Also, remember elasticsearch use approximation to tradeoff for performance. You can control this using precision_threshold up to some extent. Good explanation available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct values count in elastic search use cardinality aggregation.